# How to configure npm to use maven folder structure and war deployment

Tags: maven, typescript, npm, angular, war

I began my first pure front end project. I want to deploy it the java/maven. So i set up a normal war project:

```
│   package.json
│   pom.xml
│   tsconfig.json
│   typings.json
│
│
├───src
│   └───main
│       ├───resources
│       └───webapp
│           │   index.html
│           │
│           ├───app
│           │       app.component.ts
│           │       main.ts
│           │
│           ├───css
│           │       styles.css
│           │
│           └───WEB-INF
│                   web.xml
│
```

My problem is how to set the path to index.html/the source relative to package. json? Since this is an angular/typescript project there is also some typescript specific stuff. but my hope is to set the "source" path once and for all in package json?!

I am also not sure if i want to deploy the stuff in "webapp" directly since there are Compiling steps. So any advice how to structure a pur front end project for maven/war deployment are welcome.

Comment: thanks for advice, this is what i tried in mean time. but i am not sure how to configuring war packaging this way. but i think this advice is worth an "answer"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to integrate NPM with Maven, you could make use of [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) which I think will be a great tool for your *compiling steps*.

So, in order to configure everything together this how your *pom.xml* should look like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.14-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Artifact Name</name>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <!-- Plug-in definition -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- frontend-maven plug-in -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.29</version>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v5.10.1</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>3.8.6</npmVersion>
                    <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                    <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!-- install node & npm -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <!--npm install -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <!-- npm run build -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven WAR plug-in -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

As you can see, first we define the usage of *frontend-maven-plugin*:

- we use the most recent [stable NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) version: v5.10.1;
- the most recent version of [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm): 3.8.6;
- since the plugin downloads and installs NodeJS and NPM, one needs to declare the installation directory (**installDirectory**). I've opted to store everything on Maven's *target* directory;
- then it's necessary to define one's working directory (**workingDirectory**), which basically is the directory where our *package.json* will be. In your case, it will be at the same level as your *pom.xml* file, so we use *${basedir}* for that;
- following, it will be necessary to define the executions: the first two I believe that are quite straightforward; the last one simply assumes that, inside your *package.json*, there's a *script* target named **build** which will, for example, call the *browserify* command in order to build a *bundle.js* file:

  ```
  "scripts": {
      "build": "browserify src/main/webapp/app.js -o src/main/webapp/modules/bundle.js"
  }
  ```

  In your case, instead of the *app.js*, the *package.json* would interact with your typescript files.

---

Finally, one has the definition of the [Maven WAR plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/index.html). The only configuration made was the mention to the location where the *web.xml* is.

Notice that, by definition, Maven will package everything that's inside **src/main/webapp** directory. So, if there are any files (or folders) that you'd like to exclude, you should make use of the configuration parameter [<packagingExcludes>](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html):

```
<!-- Maven WAR plug-in -->
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
        <packagingExcludes>app/**</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The configuration above would exclude the folder *app*.

Again, this is a starting point. From here, you could play with Maven in order to custom build your application.

Comment: thanks, for this detailed guide. its more than a starting point ;-)

Comment: i have one additional question: in my case i use different "scripts" and i am not sure how to set "src/main/webapp/" as root for all of them on the other hand and how to run all those scripts and let them now about "src/main/webapp/" and "/target". eg.""start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "". how to run this and let it use /src/main/webapp ? (all my target are from angular2 tutorial)

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with Angular2... yet! :) Nevertheless, I believe that you have a *root* script. On that *root* script, you should call your other scripts taking into account their path on *src/main/webapp*, like **src/main/webapp/scritps/script1** for instance. Regarding the *target* folder, basically only Maven should be aware of that folder. Therefore, the building order of your app should be: 1. Run scripts; 2. Build app.; 3. Package app. This way, your app doesn't need to be aware of the *target* folder. Don't know if I've answer your doubts...

Comment: thanks but in my index.html are references to js-dependencies like node-modules/.... By using the frontent plugin this should change to .../target/node-modules/.. . But "target is not deployed" and i don't want to deploy hole "node-modules". On the other hand "lite-server" deploys something that is working but i am not sure how to package a correct war.

Comment: What you could do is copy the node_modules, with only the dependencies you need, during the WAR packaging phase. Something like this: `<configuration><webResources><webResource><directory>node_modules</directory><targetPath>node_modules</targetPath><includes><include>dep1/*</include><include>dep2/*</include></includes></webResource></configuration>`. Then, you just need to modify the elements that use those node_modules' dependencies in order to access them in the right way.